# How to calculate the sum of specific columns in R and make the results in a another column

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, columnsorting

I'm a beginner  in biostatistics and R software, and I need your help in a issue,
I have a table that contains more than 170 columns and more than 6000 lines, I want to add another column that contains the sum of all the columns, except the columns one and two columns

so for example if I have the data of 5 columns from A to E

```
A     B     C     D    E
12   2     13    98    6
10   7      8    67  12
12   56    67    9    7
```

I want to add another column (Column F for example ) that contain the sum of columns C D and E ( that means all the columns except the first two columns

so the result will be

```
A     B     C     D      E        F
AA    2     13    98     6        117
CF    7      8    67     12       87
QZ    56    67    9      7        83
```

Please tell me if you want to know any other informations or clarification
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(F = sum(c_across(-c(A:B))))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Rowwise: 
      A     B     C     D     E     F
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    12     2    13    98     6   117
2    10     7     8    67    12    87
3    12    56    67     9     7    83
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 5
      A     B     C     D     E
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    12     2    13    98     6
2    10     7     8    67    12
3    12    56    67     9     7
```

Comment: thank you very much for yuur answer , actually , both A and B columns are not numeric , they contain carachters , so both commands didn't work , i got  this error message :   
 Erreur : unexpected symbol in:"tabkraken4 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(F = sum(c_across(-c(tabkraken4$ScientificName:tabkraken$Rank)))tabkraken4" 
also i tried rowSums and it shows an error message said that x is not numeric , thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tbl <-
tibble::tribble(
  ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D, ~E,
  12, 2, 13,  98,  6,
  10, 7, 8,   67,  12,
  12, 56, 67,  9,  7
)


tbl %>% dplyr::mutate("F" =  C + D + E )
## R might consider F to be abbreviation for FALSE, so i put it in ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find the information you need in the top answer to this question:

stackoverflow.com/questions/3991905/sum-rows-in-data-frame-or-matrix

Basically, you just name your new column, use the `rowSums` function, and specify the columns you want to include with the square bracket subsetting.

```
data$new <- rowSums( data[,43:167] )
```

Comment: thank you very much for yuur answer , actually , the first and second columns are not numeric , they contain carachters , so both commands didn't work !

Comment: the square bracket is just an example for subsetting. Pick the columns you need to sum. in your example it would be `df$f <- rowSums(df[,3:5])`